# No aplica atributo checked a radio al hacer el collapse de bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Tengo este código:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="radio">
     <label>
      <input type="radio" name="optionsPago" value="1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTarjeta" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTarjeta">
        Tarjeta Crédito/Débito
     </label>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseTarjeta">
     <div class="well">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4 form-group campo-obligatorio">
        <label>Número de Tarjeta</label>
        <div id="numero-tarjeta" class="form-control"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 form-group campo-obligatorio">
        <label>CVC</label>
        <div id="cvc-tarjeta" class="form-control"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 form-group campo-obligatorio">
        <label>Expiración</label>
        <div id="expiracion-tarjeta" class="form-control"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="token">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
     <label>
      <input type="radio" name="optionsPago" value="2">
       Oxxo Pay
     </label>
    </div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se seleccione el primero `radio` se despliegue los campos: Número de Tarjeta, CVC y Expiración. El problema es que no me selecciona ese radio, si despliega los campos pero no deja seleccionado el `radio`

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para poner en fragmento de código ejecutable y sí selecciona el radio, el problema es que con cada clic muestra u oculta los datos de tarjeta, independientemente de la opción que se haya seleccionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar el `href` por `data-target` asi:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="radio">
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="optionsPago" value="1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTarjeta" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTarjeta">
    Tarjeta Crédito/Débito
 </label>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseTarjeta">
 <div class="well">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 form-group campo-obligatorio">
    <label>Número de Tarjeta</label>
    <div id="numero-tarjeta" class="form-control"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2 form-group campo-obligatorio">
    <label>CVC</label>
    <div id="cvc-tarjeta" class="form-control"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2 form-group campo-obligatorio">
    <label>Expiración</label>
    <div id="expiracion-tarjeta" class="form-control"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="token">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="radio">
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="optionsPago" value="2">
   Oxxo Pay
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Creo que hace falta algo más: 1 cuando se hace click en TC opera como alternador de modo que si se cambia a oxxo y se regresa oculta los campos de TC. 2. La segunda opción debiera ocultar los campos de TC. Tu respuesta **resuelve un aspecto** pero deja vivos los problemas de fondo (aunque al parecer OP aún no los ha enfrentado)